# Is there a way to make a table of data from a JSON output with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm new to coding and especially new to JSON and I was wondering if there's a way to turn the following output into a table of data. Thanks :)

```
import json
import requests
manager_history_url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/entry/151515/history/'
r = requests.get(manager_history_url).json()
print(r['current'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next example to put the data into Panda's dataframe:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

manager_history_url = (
    "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/entry/151515/history/"
)
r = requests.get(manager_history_url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r["current"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   event  points  total_points     rank  rank_sort  overall_rank  bank  value  event_transfers  event_transfers_cost  points_on_bench
0      1      68            68  1725839    1732015       1725838     0   1000                0                     0                6
1      2      54           122  5199752    5200844       2942283     0   1000                0                     0                6
2      3      66           188   544944     545247       1068695    14   1001                2                     0                8
3      4      76           264  1701243    1702381        604535    14   1001                0                     0                5
4      5      51           315  7486710    7487155       1936710    14   1003                0                     0                3
5      6      56           371  1609882    1610502       1314429     6   1004                2                     0                3
6      7       0           371  6582907    6630334       1300746     7   1003                1                     0                0
7      8      66           437  1082654    1084716        729789     7   1004                0                     0                0
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to use Pandas:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
manager_history_url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/entry/151515/history/'
r = requests.get(manager_history_url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(r['current'])
print(df)
```